# How does one trigger an enter key event on a text input field in the presence of a button in the same form?

Tags: javascript, html

## Problem

When one attaches an `onkeyup` event callback to an `<input type=text">` element, the event is triggered when the enter key is pressed and the text input element is focussed.

When one attaches an `onkeyup` event callback to an `<input type=text">` element, the event is **not** triggered when the enter key is pressed and the text input element is foccussed **if** an `<input type="submit">` element exists in the same form.

## Example code

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" required>
    <input id="eggs" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    box = document.getElementById("eggs");
    box.onkeyup = function(key) {
        console.log(key);
    };
</script>
```

## Actual and expected results

**Actual:**

The following happens when there is no `<input type="submit">` element in the same form:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ceLV.png

The following happens where there is a `<input type="submit">` element in the same form:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH9ki.png

**Expected:**

An event should be fired when the enter key is pressed, regardless of whether there is a button in the form.

Comment: either attach an onsubmit handler to the form and preventDefault() or make the input a button to not submit the form

Comment: I'm not sure either of those would work in my specific case, because: (1) I will have multiple `<input type=text">` elements that I will be listening to for key presses, and I need to know which one has focussed when the enter button was pressed. (2) I do need a submit button as the form will need to be submitted.

Comment: the onsubmithandler won't affect (1), and (2) you can still have a button that submits the form (via javascript); just not automaticly

Comment: Can you share a Fiddle/Codepen link for us to try out?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mwx9gjur/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:
1. prevent a keydown on the form from submitting the form (you could check for the right key to make a Shift+Enter still submit the form f.e.)
2. set an event handler on the submit button to actually submit the form.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <h3>Enter key event will not fire:</h3>
        <form method="post" id="form">
            <input type="text" required>
            <input id="eggs" type="text">
            <input type="submit" id="submit">
        </form>

    <script>
    eggsbox = document.getElementById("eggs");
    eggsbox.onkeyup = function(key) {
        console.log(key);
    };

      form = document.getElementById("form");
      form.onkeydown = function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode==13) {  // only prevent on Enter (otherwide you can't type anything...)
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      }

      submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
      submitButton.onClick = function(e) {
           form = document.getElementById("form");
           form.submit();  // this will also trigger the validation!
      }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wcskdL1o/

Comment: This is great, as: (1) The text box that was focussed when the enter button was pressed gets the enter key event as if it was any other event. (2) I can choose to not call `preventDefault()` if a condition is met, to make the enter key behave like normal again. (3) The form still works as a normal form (with the enter key submitting the form) if javascript is turned off. It ticks every single box. Thank you very much.

Comment: _sidenote:_ for your first question this was very well asked & described!

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('eggs').onkeydown = function(x){
   if(x.keyCode == 13){
     // submit or try using <button>...</button> instead of <a>
   }
};
```

Comment: no, the OP doesn't what the form to be submitted on enter (while in the input field). The other way round.

Comment: sidenote: Ctrl+K formats a text as code (or indent it by 4 spaces)

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I already have this code and it does not work and does not fire an event for the enter key.